# Proof of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Consider the space $C^1(\mathbb{R}) =\{f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}: f'$ exists and is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\}$ and for$f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$,
>
> define
> $$\|f\|_\infty=sup\{|f|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ and $$\|f'\|_\infty=sup\{|f'|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
> Prove or disprove:$d(f,g)=\|f-g\|_\infty+\|f'-g'\|_\infty$ is a metric on $C^1(\mathbb{R})$

The following is what I have proved

(1)Since $d(f,g)=0$ ,we can know $\|f-g\|_\infty=0$ and $\|f'-g'\|_\infty=0$ so $f=g$

(2)$d(f,g)\geq0$

(3)It is symmetric since $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$

(4)How can I prove that it satisfied with triangle inequality that $d(f,g)\leq d(f,h)+d(h,g)$ ?

Comment: Have you checked whether $d(f,g) < \infty$ for all $f,g\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1):

For the solution of your exercise you should follow the hint

> Have you checked whether $d(f,g)<\infty$ for all $f,g\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$? – from Prahlad Vaidyanathan

But to ask your question:

Use the definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, add $0$, use the triangle inequality for real values and the properties of the supremum and you get
\begin{align}
\|f-h\|_\infty&=\sup\{|f(x)-h(x)|~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)+g(x)-h(x)|~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&\color{red}{\leq}\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-h(x)|~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&\color{red}{\leq}\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\}+\sup\{|g(x)-h(x)|~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&=\|f-g\|_\infty+\|g-h\|_\infty.
\end{align}
Same way you can prove $\|f'-h'\|_\infty\leq\|f'-g'\|_\infty+\|g'-h'\|_\infty$ and together it yields $d(f,h)\leq d(f,g)+d(g,h)$.